# Fail Gradle Copy task if source directory not exist

Tags: gradle, copy

I'm using Gradle to create a build script. I want to protect the script from wrong properties, one of the tasks in the script is simple Copy task and I notice that when I put non-exist directory as `from` parameter the task continue with `Skipping task ':copySpecificPlatform' as it has no source files.`

Is there a way to cause the copy task to fail in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
task cp(type: Copy) {
    from 'empty'
    into 'target'
    inputs.sourceFiles.stopExecutionIfEmpty()
}
```

Every [Task](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DefaultTask.html) has its [TaskInputs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs.html) which source files are a [FileCollection](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html) that has special [method](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html#stopExecutionIfEmpty()) which configures the desired behavior.

Comment: Note that this way, the test is done at initialization. This means: also a second clean will fail if the first clean removed the file. Unfortunately, putting it to doFirst is also not an option because this is not executed if the file doesn't exist (gradle 4.2)

Comment: `stopExecutionIfEmpty` is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
task copySpecificPlatform(type: Copy) {
    from 'source/directory'
    into 'target/directory'
    if(inputs.sourceFiles.empty) throw new StopExecutionException("No files found")
}
```

Comment: From the docs for `StopExecutionException`: _Note that throwing this exception does not fail the execution of the task or the build._ I think this is not what we want.