# Gradle copy task fails silently

Tags: gradle

I have a copy task for 1 file

```
task myCopyTask(type: Copy) {
    copy {
        from "/path/to/my/file"
        into "path/to/out/dir"
    }
}
```

How to do, so the task fails if the copy fails? Right now if the file does not exist, it does not give an error.

---

[Fail Gradle Copy task if source directory not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130067/fail-gradle-copy-task-if-source-directory-not-exist) gives a solution. This does not work, because if everything is not inside of

```
copy { ... }
```

the task does not work at all.

---

I tried also

```
task myCopyTask(type: Copy) {
    copy {
        from "/path/to/my/file"
        into "path/to/out/dir"
        inputs.sourceFiles.stopExecutionIfEmpty()
    }
}
```

The above would fail, as inputs.sourceFiles would be empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why don't you specify your task as:

```
task myCopyTask(type: Copy) {
    from "/path/to/my/file"
    into "path/to/out/dir"
    inputs.sourceFiles.stopExecutionIfEmpty()
}
```

This would work as expected during execution phase, while your solution would try to copy something during configuration phase of the build every time you call any task.

Comment: the method was removed

Answer (score 3):

The very first definition of the tasks actually doesn't do what you expect from the task:

```
task myCopyTask(type: Copy) {
copy {
    from "/path/to/my/file"
    into "path/to/out/dir"
}
```

is acutually same as

```
task myCopyTask(type: Copy) {
    project.copy {
        from "/path/to/my/file"
        into "path/to/out/dir"
    }
}
```

And it will execute `copy` action during task configuration, no matter if the task is called or not.

What you need is:

```
task myCopyTask(type: Copy) {
    from "/path/to/my/file"
    into "path/to/out/dir"

    doFirst {
        if(inputs.empty) throw new GradleException("Input source for myCopyTask doesn't exist")
    }
}
```

Comment: `inputs.empty` does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This solution for Kotlin DSL works for me:

```
tasks.register<Copy>("myCopyTask") {
    val path = "/path/to/my/file"
    from(path)
    into("path/to/out/dir")
    if (inputs.sourceFiles.isEmpty) {
        throw GradleException("File not found: $path")
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider explaining your code a bit to help other understand your answer more